# QTMouseEvent localPos() has offset

Tags: c++, qt

using mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) to register an event and reading the coordinates with QPointF localPos(event->localPos()); results in reading shifted y-Coordinates by roughly 10.

Why is that?

Comment: Tell us more, how do you know that you have an offset ? With which value do you make a comparison ?

Comment: I display the coordinates clicked and I have visual feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation for `QWidget` I found the function `mapFromGlobal()`.

The following returns the correct mapped coordinates:

```
QPoint globalPos(event->globalPos());
QPoint localPos(ui.Picture->mapFromGlobal(globalPos));
```